# XSLT: XPath context and document()

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xalan

I have an XSLT like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                         xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan">

  <xsl:variable name="fooDocument" select="document('fooDocument.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$fooDocument//*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="nodeInFooDocument">
    <xsl:variable name="valueFromSource" select="//someSourceElement"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

In the second template, which matches nodes in the `fooDocument.xml` which is loaded with `document()`, I want to access nodes in the XML source the transformation is executed upon. This does not work with `//someSourceElement`, because apparently, XPath executes this path in the context of fooDocument.

A first workaround that comes to mind is this:

```
...
<!-- global variable -->
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

...
<!-- in the template -->
<xsl:variable name="valueFromSource" select="$root//someSourceElement"/>

...
```

But I cannot use this workaround, because actually, my variable is selected like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="valueFromSource" select="xalan:evaluate($someXPathString)"/>
```

`$someXPathString` is not crafted in the XSLT file, but loaded from fooDocument (and contains an absolute path like the one used above). Still, I need to somehow change the XPath context back to the XML source. A *very* hacky workaround I found is this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$root[1]">
  <xsl:variable name="valueFromSource" select="xalan:evaluate($someXPathString)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The (useless) `for-each` loop changes the context back to the main XML source, thus the XPath evaluates correctly. But obviously, this is not an acceptable solution.

Is there a way to do this *right*, or can someone suggest a better workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you think your attempt with a `for-each select="$root"` to change the context document is not acceptable this is the right approach. So use that, there is no other way.

Comment: I agree that for-each is a fine way to change the context document (if somewhat non-intuitive), but surely Martin you don't mean that there is no other way. E.g. `apply-templates select="$root"` (with or without mode) will also set the context document, right?

Comment: I did not find any other feasible way to change the context document.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered doing all the computation that constructs $someXPathString using a series of global variables?

```
<xsl:variable name="fooDocument" select="document('fooDocument.xml')"/>

<xsl:variable name="temp1"
  .. some computation using fooDocument ..
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="temp2"
  .. some computation using temp1 ..
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="someXPathString"
  .. some computation using temp2 ..
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="root" select="xalan:evaluate($someXPathString)"/>
```

Comment: This would work if I chose to copy all the contents of fooDocument into a global variable and use xalan:nodeset() on it. As fooDocument contains a sequence of arbitrary length, I cannot split it into a fixed number of global variables holding primitive values. For readability, this is definitely an option. EDIT: On second thought, when I use `apply-templates` on this global variable, my context would still not be on the XML source, but on the variable which contains the result of a xalan:nodeset() call.